# Importing a TermDocumentMatrix into R

Tags: text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix

I am working on a qualitative analysis project in the tm package of R. I have built a corpus and created a term document matrix and long story short I need to edit my term document matrix and conflate some of its rows. To do this I have  exported it out of R using

```
write.csv()
```

I then have imported the csv file back into R but am struggling to figure out how to get R to read it as a `TermDocumentMatrix` or `DocumentTermMatrix`.

I tried using the suggestions of the following example code with no avail.

It seems to keep reading my matrix as if it was a corpus and each cell as a single document.

```
# change this file location to suit your machine
file_loc <- "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Book1.csv"
# change TRUE to FALSE if you have no column headings in the CSV
 x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = TRUE)
 require(tm)
 corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
 dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

Is there any way to import in a csv matrix that will be read as a `termdocumentmatrix` or `documenttermmatrix` without having R read the csv as if each cell is a document?

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading documents, so skip the `Corpus()` step.  This should work directly:

```
myDTM <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(x, weighting = weightTf)
```

For next time, consider saving the TDM object as .RData as this will not require conversion, and is also much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the format of any data, I would recommend to use the [save() function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html).
You can save any R objects into a .RData file. And when you want to retrieve the data, you can use the load() function.